# Responsive horizontally scrollable image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have stuck with making a responsive, horizontally scrollable gallery. Namely, I have some issues with layout and responsiveness.

All images have the same fixed height - 1200px. The width is variable in 850px~1200px.

**Problem is that - I want every image to have the maximum height the viewport allows while keeping the correct aspect ratio with a text title below that image. This iamge+title should be responsive, i.e. keep that behavior on both mobile and desktop Chrome/Safari**

The result should look like
[image]

Here is a simple code to reproduce the problem:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling-gallery {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: clip;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  gap: 2px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: max-content;
}

.large-image {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
}

.medium-image {
  width: 850px;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <h1>Horizontal Gallery</h1>

    <div class="scrolling-gallery">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="large-image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_blue.png" />
        <h2>Image 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="medium-image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_850_1200_red.png" />
        <h2>Image 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="large-image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_green.png" />
        <h2>Image 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have made the part with the image but struggle to add the image titles. This is the website I'm working on: https://alisatrapsh.com/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your exact problem? Is it a problem with responsiveness or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using css **calc()** will help to manage the heights.

I just modified the total height of gallery from 1200 to `calc(100vh - 0px)` but later you can set it to any other amount like `calc(100vh - 50px)` where 50 px is reserved for top title.

The secret for image descriptios is also to use the `calc(100% - 40px)` for image height and `40px` (or any other amount) for image description.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling-gallery {
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: clip;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  gap: 2px;
  height:calc(100vh - 0px);
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%;
}

.image-container img{
  height:calc(100% - 40px);
}

.image-container h2{
  height:40px;
  font-size:10pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
   

    <div class="scrolling-gallery">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_blue.png" />
        <h2>Image 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img  src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_850_1200_red.png" />
        <h2>Image 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_green.png" />
        <h2>Image 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've taken your solution and tested it thoroughly and it works, the only thing I've changed as using `svh` instead of `vh`, for safari on mobile it takes care of the bottom navigation pane.

Comment: if you have dynamic titles height - this is broken

Comment: or if the width `<h2>` is greater than the width of the image - this is broken 

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of the `calc()` function and `svh` units will give the best result.

I used developer tools to get an approximate height for the page elements; this could be done via javascript, but it is probably easier to keep it static.

It is best to use svh units because they take into account the space actually available on a screen, taking into account the navigation bars of different browsers.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling-gallery {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: clip;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  gap: 2px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: max-content;
}

.image {
  height: calc(100svh - 50px - 40px - 35px);
  /* 50px => ~H1 height */
  /* 30px => ~H2 height */
  /* 35px => ~height of the scollbar (might change depending on the browser, but 35px should be the biggest)
  */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <h1>Horizontal Gallery</h1>

    <div class="scrolling-gallery">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_blue.png" />
        <h2>Image 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_850_1200_red.png" />
        <h2>Image 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_green.png" />
        <h2>Image 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, svh is something I have figured out to add to the solution posted by Ali earlier.

Comment: if you have dynamic titles height - this is broken

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the headers is dynamic, you will have to add little javascript:

```js
window.onload = initGallery;
window.onresize = initGallery;

function initGallery() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.image-container').forEach(el => el.style.width = el.querySelector('img').clientWidth + 'px');
  document.querySelectorAll('.scrolling-gallery').forEach(el => el.style.opacity = 1);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

h1 {
  flex: none;
  padding: 6pt;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.scrolling-gallery {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  gap:2px;
  /* so that the jump is not visible after loading pictures */
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

.image-container h2 {
  flex: none;
  padding: 6pt;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<h1>Horizontal<br> Gallery</h1>
<div class="scrolling-gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_blue.png">
    <h2>Image<br> 1<br>✌️ </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="medium-image" src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_850_1200_red.png">
    <h2>Image 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://temp-image-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/distortion_matrix_1200_1200_green.png">
    <h2>Image 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```